# How to receive notifications for updates in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have formulated all cells in my Google Sheet, but since they are not counted as edits (since it is formualated update and not manual edit), I am not receiving notifications when there are updates in the value of the cell. Is there a way to set up notifications for updates in a Google Sheet, regardless of whether the cells are edited or not?

In Addition, Can I send the notification of these update in Discord/Whatsapp/Telegram?

Thanks.

I tried set up with zapier, iftt, etc. But it doesnt work since it is not edited.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

That can only be done with a programmatic solution. It is probably easiest to do with [Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

If the value in the formula cell depends on some other cells that are manually edited, use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to monitor the manually edited cells rather than the formula cell.

If you need to monitor the value in a formula cell, use a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to check the value periodically, and compare the value to the cell's previous value that you store in the [Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) service.

Comment: Yeah I tried with app script but i could not figure it out :(

Everything is formulated in the gsheet so i can only only do it in the formulated cell unfortunately